# How to use the value of a variable in creating an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var obj = {fields : []};
```

And a variable:

```
var x = "property_name";
```

Now how do I use the value in the variable x as the property name for the object that I'm going to push inside the array?

I tried something like the one below, but it takes `x` literally and uses it as the property name. What I want to use is the value stored in the variable `x`. Is that possible?

```
obj.fields.push({x : 'im a value'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the object literal syntax for this purpose. However, you *can* create a new object and then use the `[]` syntax - remember, `obj.xyz` is equivalent to `obj['xyz']` - but as you can see with the quotes in the latter, you can use an *expression* there - such as a variable:

```
var x = "property_name";
var obj = {};
obj[x] = 'value';
obj.fields.push(obj);
```

Comment: And then there is the one who's name is mentioned at the risk of eternal damnation in agony while loved ones suffer: `var x = 'property_name'; var obj = eval('({' + x + ': "value"})');`. Agggh, the lights are fading...!

Comment: Ew, go away with that ev[ia]l stuff :P